# Luigi : Step by Step instructions not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, luigi

I'm a newbie to python, I've installed Luigi-2.0.1 on my RHEL linux. Trying to run a sample program

```
import luigi

class MyTask(luigi.Task) :
        param = luigi.Parameter(default=42)

        def requires(self):
                return SomeOtherTask(self.param)

        def run(self):
                f = self.output.open('w')
                print >>f, 'hello world'
                f.close()

        def output(self):
                return luigi.LocalTarget('/tmp/foo/bar-%s.txt' % self.param)

if __name__ == '__main__':
        luigi.run()
```

Executed the following command

```
luigi --module maintask.py MyTask
```

I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/luigi", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2655, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 648, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 546, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: python-daemon<3.0
```

Upon investigating the web, I could not figure out why this happened. I have python 2.6. Is it that luigi is not compatible with 2.6 and only works for python 3.0 onwards?.

Appreciate any help

Comment: Forgot to mention, the program should throw an error for the missing SomeOtherTask(self.param)

Comment: the error tells you that there's a missing dependency, specifically `python-daemon` (but there might be other missing dependencies as well)

Comment: Also you probably will need to use `self.output().open(...)`

Comment: What is the name of the file that contains `MyTask`?

Comment: What is the name of the file that contains `MyTask`? [The docs](http://luigi.readthedocs.org/en/stable/command_line.html#running-from-the-command-line) suggest that you should run `luigi --module maintask MyTask` (i.e. no `.py`).

Comment: it is maintask.py in which the above code is written.

Answer (score 5):

From Luigi's [package page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/luigi):

> Luigi is a Python (2.7, 3.3, 3.4) package that helps you build complex pipelines of batch jobs.

You will have to upgrade from 2.6 if you want to use this.

Comment: Thank you all for your inputs. I have python upgraded to 3.5. Luigi seems to have got installed based on the following response. 
$  luigi
No task specified